# How can I fix a python requests TypeError Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am currently working on a script that logs into study.com and displays the assignments to due. But I keep facing a `TypeError` Error.

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from colorama import Fore, init

# initializing the colors
init()
init(convert=True)

# log in info
data = {
    'username': 'insert email here',
    'password': 'insert password here',
    'remember-me': 'on'
}

# headers
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
}


with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://study.com/academy/login.html')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    data['_csrf'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': '_csrf'})['value']
    r = s.post('https://study.com/academy/login.ajax',
               data=data, headers=headers)
    if 'memberDashboard' in r.text:
        print(Fore.GREEN + 'Logged in.')
    else:
        print('Error. Wrong email or password')
```

This code returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 25, in <module>
    data['_csrf'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': '_csrf'})['value']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm quite new to python so I have no idea what a `TypeError` error actually means.

Comment: Your `soup.find()` seems to return `None`. This is how it indicates that you didn't find anything. You should always test for the return value being `None`.

Comment: Oh but this worked for the first few times. Why did it suddenly stop?

Comment: Ok, that's a different question.

Comment: Most likely something wrong with the data you are receiving rather than the `find` method of `soup`.